# A link to the server could not be established for unknown reason

Tags: php, mysql, class, object, database-connection

I got little consfused, I really need some fresh view on the code :) 
This is my **translate function**:

```
function __($string) {
    isset($_SESSION['lang']) ? $lang = $_SESSION['lang'] : $lang = DEFAULT_LANG;
    $oDb = new Model_Database('translations');
    $aLang = $oDb->getById($string);
    return $aLang[$lang];
}
```

This is **Model_Database** that it uses:

```
class Model_Database {

   static private $connection = '';
   private $aConfig;
   private $sTable;

   public function __construct($sTable = '') {
       $this->aConfig = Core_Config::GetConfigArray('database');
       if(empty(self::$connection)) {
           self::$connection = mysql_connect($this->aConfig['host'], $this->aConfig['user'], $this->aConfig['pass']);
       }
       mysql_select_db($this->aConfig['db'], self::$connection);
       $this->sTable = TABLE_PREFIX . $sTable;
    }

    public function getById($id) {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM `' . $this->sTable . '` WHERE `id` = "' . $id . '"';
        $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        return $result;
    }

    public function getByAny($column, $value) {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM `' . $this->sTable . '` WHERE `' . $column . '` = "' . $value .'"';
        $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        return $result;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        if( gettype(self::$connection) == "resource") {
            mysql_close(self::$connection);
        }
        self::$connection = '';
    }
}
```

And this is **Model_Login** that also uses database:

```
class Model_Login {

    private $oDatabase;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->oDatabase = new Model_Database('users');
    }

    public function login($login, $password) {
        $aUser = $this->oDatabase->getByAny('login', $login);
        if(md5($password) == $aUser['password']) {
           $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
           $_SESSION['password'] = md5($password);
           return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to use **translation function** in the file responsible for logging in, I get error `Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'` and `A link to the server could not be established`.
At first I got problems with closing and opening new connections and logging in worked but translation didn't. So I found the solution in remembering the connection as static variable. Translation started to work but logging in stopped.
Any advices?
**EDIT:** The error shows up when I click "login" which creates new **Model_Login** and calls method *login()*
**EDIT 2:** If you need any more code to reproduce the error I can even share whole project, it's in early building phase as you can see, just making basic functionalities. Of course I can just post some little more code if needed, just specify what do you need to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the solution by the time of waiting this way:
 
1. I added this method to the database class

```
public function checkConnection() {
        if( gettype(self::$connection) != "resource") {
            self::$connection = mysql_connect($this->aConfig['host'], $this->aConfig['user'], $this->aConfig['pass']);
            mysql_select_db($this->aConfig['db'], self::$connection);
        }

    }
```

2. I added this method to every other method in the first line.

Solution works but isn't very "pretty", do you know any better way to do this?

**EDIT:** I found simplier solution.
Instead of *checkConnection()* I made *closeConnection()* method and added it at the end of my **index.php** (whole site works as an app, everything goes through **index.php**). Also deleted the **destructor** from database class.Here's the code, hope someone will learn on my faults :) :

```
public static function closeConnection() {
    if( gettype(self::$connection) == "resource") {
        mysql_close(self::$connection);
        self::$connection = '';
    }
}
```